# SVN externals property is missing in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Why is it when I right-click on a folder in Tortoise SVN, click on Properties and then Click 'New...' in the property name dropdown, the svn:externals is missing?

I'm new to subversion/tortoise. However I want to evaluate the software. I wanted to try out the externals feature but I'm stumped at the first hurdle.

If I enter svn:external manually and then set the folder to point to the 'trunk' folder, I get the following error:
Error parsing svn:externals property on 'file:///...' etc.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The feature works just fine for me, and many others I think.  svn:externals would be missing if you were trying to set the properties of a file.  Can you post either a screenshot or an exact replica of the string you are using to specify the external link ?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you re-install TortoiseSVN. The  svn:externals option should be the third one listed in the dropdown (with the current version 1.6.7), when you go to add a new property.

**Note:** This option is visible when adding the property to your working folder, not when using repo-browser. I am not sure why TortoiseSVN makes this distinction, since the externals references do get committed to the repo.

I am guessing the reason your `file:///` reference is failing is that when doing it through repo-browser, the SVN server (which is what you are actually making the change on at this point) is not able to see your local file system.

In general, I recommend that you makes changes in your working folder rather than directly on the repo via repo-browser. This way you can make sure you get things right before you commit.

You can read up more on externals [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

Comment: I think you've got it! The properties shows up for a folder that I've just checked out too.  Still a bit confused though. I have my folder which is empty because this will form the destination folder of the shared code.  Not sure what I put in the property value. Whether this should be the link to the checked out trunk folder or the repository url.

I just don't know enough about Subversion to trial this feature out.

Comment: Yeah I've tried this, I have 2 folders:
\trunk
\customer

Customer is empty because I want this to have the trunk code.
Set svn:externals value on the customer to point to trunk but everytime I enter a path I get 'Error Parsing svn:Externals property on'....weird

Comment: You need to use an SVN URL to the repository for the externals value, not just point to a folder on your local machine. The exception is if the repo exists on your local machine, and you are accessing via the file:/// protocol. But even then you are using the SVN file:/// protocol. So, your value would typically be `svn://myreposerver.com/myproject/mybranch` or similar.

Comment: You can read up more on externals here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is at specifying the **Property value**.
Probably you're missing the name of the external folder.
When you open window for adding the properties, as a 'Property Name' enter *svn:externals* and as a 'Property Value' enter the name you want to give to the external folder followed by the path to your repository.
Example: *MyExternalFolderName file:///...*

Then after you update your Working dir, SVN will create new directory with name MyExternalFolderName and will copy files from 'file:///...'

Answer (score 0):

You should enter "svn:externals" (notice the plural). There are some versions of Tortoise that don't display this property. Please post your properties content so we can better understand what may be happening.

Comment: I have this already set: svn:externals.
I don't understand why its complaining. Is svn:externals a new feature? I have latest tortoise but maybe need newer version of SVN?

Comment: What do you have in your properties, it looks like it is not being parsed properly.

Comment: I've just re-installed TortoiseSVN.
In the Repo-browser, I click Properties and then New...
These are the following property names:
svn:eol-style
svn:executable
svn:keywords
svn:needs-lock
svn:mime-type

This list looks much reduced to what I have seen in tutorials etc. Either there is something wrong with SVN or I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Right click-> tortoise svn -> properties, new and select svn:externals

Is you wanna add it to the context, simply do:

Right click-> tortoise svn -> settings

In the general tab, select **context menu** and mark properties